# The LEVEL clause includes a reserved word or argument that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\vladut.moraru\Desktop\TCO Orders\02_Template_BOM.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""

                Dim pram As OleDbParameter
                Dim dr As DataRow
                Dim olecon As OleDbConnection
                Dim olecomm As OleDbCommand
                Dim olecomm1 As OleDbCommand
                Dim oleadpt As OleDbDataAdapter
                Dim ds As DataSet
                Try
                    olecon = New OleDbConnection
                    olecon.ConnectionString = connstring
                    olecomm = New OleDbCommand
                    olecomm.CommandText = "Select Level, F_N, Name, Rev from [BOM$]"
                    olecomm.Connection = olecon
                    olecomm1 = New OleDbCommand
                    olecomm1.CommandText = "Insert into [BOM$] " & "(Level, F_N, Name, Rev) values " & "(@FName, @LName, @Age, @Phone)"
                    olecomm1.Connection = olecon
                    pram = olecomm1.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar)
                    pram.SourceColumn = "Level"
                    pram = olecomm1.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar)
                    pram.SourceColumn = "F_N"
                    pram = olecomm1.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar)
                    pram.SourceColumn = "Name"
                    pram = olecomm1.Parameters.Add("@Phone", OleDbType.VarChar)
                    pram.SourceColumn = "Rev"
                    oleadpt = New OleDbDataAdapter(olecomm)
                    ds = New DataSet
                    olecon.Open()
                    oleadpt.Fill(ds, "BOM")
                    If IsNothing(ds) = False Then
                        dr = ds.Tables(0).NewRow
                        dr("Level") = "Raman"
                        dr("F_N") = "Tayal"
                        dr("Name") = 24
                        dr("Rev") = 98989898
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)
                        oleadpt = New OleDbDataAdapter
                        oleadpt.InsertCommand = olecomm1
                        Dim i As Integer = oleadpt.Update(ds, "BOM")
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                Finally
                    olecon.Close()
                    olecon = Nothing
                    olecomm = Nothing
                    oleadpt = Nothing
                    ds = Nothing
                    dr = Nothing
                    pram = Nothing
                End Try
```

I want tot write into tamplate excel with column Level, F_N, Name, Rev and my code generate that error from title. I want to insert some value in my excel but on line oleadpt.Fill(ds, "BOM") give me that error. I put a pic with excel file. The sheet name is BOM

[image]

My question is, where i miss to generate that code? I write wrong my columns or my connection?

Comment: Try `[Level]` with brackets

Comment: As the error message says, [Level is a reserved word in Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335) you need to escape it